# Excel List Creation from another List

Tags: arrays, excel, list

Okay so here is my problem, I have a sheet that looks like this

[image: Example]

On the left I have a list of names and on the right I have a new List of names of people that have a Start number before 24 and an end number after 24. I tried using:

```
=IF(IF(AND(Monday!AS3<24,Monday!AT3>=24),"True","False")="True",Monday!B3,"Error")
```

Where `AS3` is `Start`, `AT3` is `End`, and `B3` is the `Name`. This works except I have 100 names and I don't want to have to put this formula in 100 cells to test for each person. Any help to make this take less space that would be great. After the formula goes through the end list will not be more then 15 to 20 names. So I was hoping to use no more then 20 cells to create the list. Not 100.

Comment: there's nothing wrong to use such a formula even in 1000s of rows, let alone 100. just use an [**Excel Table**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/overview-of-excel-tables-HA010048546.aspx) with autofilter and formula autofill features to make your life easier

Comment: I never said it was wrong, I said if anyone could help to make it not take up 100 cells would help greatly, I cant have it take 100 cells because I need to do this about 40 more times over several sheets and the formulas already in the sheet already slow down the document thats why I was hoping there was a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a powerful technique that uses a "helper" column to identify the *good* names.

In **D2** enter:

```
=IF(AND(B2<24,C2>24),1+MAX(D1:$D$1),"")
```

and copy down (this identifies the *good* records)

In **F2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(ROW()-1,D:D,0)-1,0),"")
```

and copy down ( this grabs the *good* names)

.
.

[image: demo]

Comment: YOU ARE A GOD, I adjusted the formulas to match what I needed and it works perfectly thank you.